# Use rvm to install ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When I tried to install ruby using rvm, it went wrong:

```
WeihongLoudeMacBook-Air:~ jeremy$ rvm use ruby --install --default

Using /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1

Warning! Executable 'ruby' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!

Warning! Executable 'gem' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!

Warning! Executable 'irb' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!
```

Comment: use this to install
     \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Comment: How did you install rvm?

Comment: Thanks all! It seems like I lost something in config files. I got it done by add "--auto-dotfiles"

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I suggest that you install rbenv instead of rvm .

Comment: How does this helps answer the question ?

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I lost something in config files. I got it done by add "--auto-dotfiles". What is the advantage of rbenv over rvm?

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer.